# "He brought the stick crashing down on his hands" Can a verb be followed by a verb?

Tags: grammar, verbs, adjectives

This statement I have come across many times. Similar ones too where crashing is replaced by some other word. Both brought and crashing are verbs, can a verb follow a verb?

Comment: Yes, verbs can follow anything. And there can be many verbs in a sentence. Each verb has its own clause, normally, though we often delete the clause markers and anything else we can predict.

Comment: Yes, I'd say that the clause "crashing down on his hands" is complement of the verb "brought". The intervening noun phrase "the stick" is direct object of "brought".

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

I think so. The subject can perform two or more actions at the same time.
"They came running into the house."
"He looked at me smiling."
"They climbed up the hill, huffing, puffing snd sweating."